# Get friend list Facebook Api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I saw, that Facebook provided new Android SDK 4.0. Who knows how to get friends list via this API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the GraphRequest class, there's a newMyFriendsRequest method. This will return you the list of friends that are also using your app, as long as your app has the user_friends permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphRequest/#newMyFriendsRequest

Comment: I know about this method, but nowhere explained how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Request friendRequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(activeSession, 
        new GraphUserListCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
                    //users contains details of all the friends the person has
            }
    });
friendRequest.executeAsync();
```